# How can i change the white background of the eps file to transparent?

Tags: inkscape, gimp, eps, white

I want to change the white background my eps log to the transparent one. I have download GIMP and INKSCAPE but i don't know what tool should I use.

The eps file is [here](http://liris.cnrs.fr/dgtal/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/browser/branches/0.3.1/doc/PosterDGCI/Images/liris-logo.eps?rev=1211)    and i donwload the png version to see what the figure looks like.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The EPS you provide has little value, it contains the logo as a bitmap image....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual technique in Gimp:

- Open the file.
- *Layer → Transparency → Add alpha channel* (if disabled then it’s already there).
- Using the wand with a low threshold (<10), select the background (shift-click on any closed areas that aren't selected, such as the inside of the upper curve of the final *S)*.
- *Select → Grow* by one pixel (the selection should include the border pixels of the letters).
- *Color → Color to alpha* and remove the white.

Result, transplanted on a contrasting red background to show the absence of halo or jagged edges:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The EPS you linked to is simply a low resolution bitmap image contained inside an EPS container. It contains no vectors.  So you can't edit it with Inkscape or other vector software.  You could of course recreate it in Inkscape if you really want to.

In GIMP try *Colors > Color to Alpha*, and click OK.

Export as PNG or TIFF if you want to maintain transparency.

Comment: Plain color-to-alpha will make the light gray bars become nearly transparent

Comment: @Xenoid - true, but it's such a crappy little image, I doubt if anyone would notice unless you were to put it on a dark/coloured background. The OP would be better trying to source the original vector file instead.

Comment: True but others could use this answer with other images. C2A is fine but for this kind of use you have to make sure it only happens where it is useful.